# Let $V_n=${ $p(x)$: $p$ is a polynomial of deg(p)$\leq n$}. Show that $V_n$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ and find a basis of $V_n$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V_n=${ $p(x)$: $p$ is a polynomial of deg(p)$\leq n$}. Show that $V_n$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ and find a basis of $V_n$.

I know that we need to show that $V_n$ is closed under addition, scalar multiplication and $0\in V_n$ but I couldn't show. Can you give a hint?

Comment: What have you tried? This is one of the simplest possible examples of a vector space. (Related: what is your specific definition of a polynomial?)

Comment: What is the result when you take arbitrary polynomials $p(x) = a_0+ a_1x + \cdots + a_nx^n$ and $q(x) = b_0 + b_1x + \cdots + b_nx^n$ of degree at most $n$ and add them together?

Comment: $0\in V_n$ but how could we say? Can you write here?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Can you write here that how could you obtain $0\in V_n$?

Comment: Kahler, the zero polynomial is considered something of a special case; but certainly at the very least you can consider it as a polynomial of degree zero $p(x) = a_0$ where $a_0=0$. (Traditionally the zero polynomial is often considered to have degree $-\infty$ for convenience, but that's less relevant here.)

Comment: You have to start off by defining addition and scalar multiplication of functions. If you already have definitions, trying summing two arbitrary polynomials and multiplying an arbitrary polynomial by an arbitrary scalar. See @StevenStadnicki's comment above for the zero element of this vector space.

Comment: @Kahler Perhaps you could let us know what you have tried just so that we can see where exactly the difficulty is arising and perhaps maybe a  bit about what level you are at coming in to this problem - what do you already know about vector spaces (e.g. if you have heard of the sub space test)... The reason I say this is that, no offence, but for a student studying vector spaces, this seems like what would usually be an easier exercise, and so it might be instructive to know where you are getting tripped up (e.g. how to phrase the argument formally?).

Answer (score 1):

From the question, it seems that you are (implicitly) already given that $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. the space of all functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$) is a vector space; $V_n$ is clearly a non-empty subset, so to show that it is a subspace, all we need to apply is the subspace test.

That is, we need to show that,

1. $\,\,\,\,\,\,0_{V_n} \in V_n \,\,\,$ (where $0_{V_n}$ is the additive identity - see note at end)
2. $\,\,\,\,\,\, \forall u, v \in V_n \,\,$ and $\,\,\forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R}, \quad \lambda u + v \in V_n $

This is relatively straightforward:

$$u = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + ... + a_nx^n,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, v = b_0 + b_1x + b_2x^2 + ... + b_nx^n$$

for some constants $a_0,a_1,...,a_n,b_0,b_1,...,b_n \in \mathbb{R}$. (Note that, the constants here are real as $V_n$ is a subspace of *real* functions. Also, some, or all, of these constants may well be zero.)

Then,

$$ \lambda u + v = (\lambda a_0 + b_0) + (\lambda a_1 + b_1)x + ... + (\lambda a_n + b_n)x^n$$

which is certainly a polynomial of degree $\leq n$, so is in $V_n$.

Hence, by the subspace test, we conclude that $V_n$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$.

For a proof of the subspace test, see: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/One-Step_Vector_Subspace_Test For more info, on the subspace test, see Google.

**Note:** Note here that I am counting the zero function as a polynomial of degree zero (this is necessary for the statement in the question to actually be true). There are also some comments to this end on the OP's question.